# How can I provide language-aware URL patterns for Pathauto?

Tags: i18n-l10n, path-aliases, tokens

I am using this pattern in Drupal 9 Pathauto to generate URLs:

```
[node:menu-link:parents:join-path]/[node:menu-link]
```

This does however not seem to work when using translated content. The generated URL keeps generating in the default language.
How can this be solved?

Thanks.